# Missing an argument for parameter on PS1

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I was trying to figured out how can I throw exception or set it to default value, once I didn't put any value on the parameter?

```
Function ConnectionStrings {

   param(
    [Parameter(
    Mandatory = $false)]

        [AllowNull()]
        [AllowEmptyString()]
    [string] $region 
   )

   try{

    if (!$regionHash.ContainsKey($region)){
        $regionHash["US"]
    } elseif (!$region) {
        $regionHash["US"]
        #$slave = $regionHash["US"].slave
        #$master =  $regionHash["US"].master
        #$track =  $regionHash["US"].tracking
    } else {
        $regionHash[$region]
        #$slave = $regionHash[$region].slave
        #$master =  $regionHash[$region].master
        #$track =  $regionHash[$region].tracking
    }
   } catch {
       Write-Warning -Message "OOPS!"
   }

 }
```

Once I run the command: `ConnectionStrings -region` It should throw an exception or set to a default value instead.

Need your guidance, I'm just new on powershell.

Thanks.

edit: Without setting the value of the parameters `ConnectionStrings -region`

Comment: Set `Mandatory = $false`

Comment: @Theo Still the same.
`PS C:\Users\tinga\Documents\DevOps\DBAScripts\Modules> ConnectionStrings -region
ConnectionStrings : Missing an argument for parameter 'region'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.String' and try again.
At line:1 char:19
+ ConnectionStrings -region
+                   ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ConnectionStrings], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument,ConnectionStrings`

Comment: If you are not sending a parameter, then you should also not specify the parameter name in the call. Remove `-region`.

Comment: @Theo Thanks for your time. So there's no solution in this kind of issue if ever a user forgot the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use both `Mandatory` and a default value for the same parameter.  Why not?  If a Param has the Mandatory` attribute, the cmdlet will prompt the user for a value, if no value is provided.

If you want to use a default value, provide one like this:

```
function Verb-Noun
{
    Param
    (
        # Param1 help description        
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]        
        $Param1 = 'default'
    )
   "value of `$param1` is $Param1"
}
```

If executed like so

```
>Verb-Noun -Param1 a
value of $param1 is a
```

But if the user does not provide a value for the parameter, the default value will be used.

```
Verb-Noun
value of $param1 is default
```

Now, if we add the `Mandatory` attribute like so...

```
Param
    (
        # Param1 help description
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]   
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]        
        $Param1 = 'default'
    )
#rest of code...
```

When the user fails to provide a value for `Param1`, the user is prompted to provide a value.  There is no opportunity for the default to be used.

```
Verb-Noun 
cmdlet Verb-Noun at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Param1: 
#function pauses and won't run until a value is provided
```